# <T> cannot be resolved to a type Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I've got three classes:

One class which handles my main game operations. Its name is 'PlatformerGame'.
Note: Removed all game-related stuff.

```
public class PlatformerGame {

    public PlatformerGame()
    {

    }

}
```

Then, I've got a class called 'PlatformerSingleton' which is meant to provide exactly one instance of the PlatformerGame.

```
public class PlatformerSingleton {

    private static PlatformerGame game;

    protected PlatformerSingleton()
    {}

    public static PlatformerGame getGame()
    {
        if (game == null)
            game = new PlatformerGame();

            return game;
    }

}
```

And lastly, I've got the entry point of my application which is supposed to do nothing but get the instance of PlatformerGame and call its 'start' method.

```
public class Entry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PlatformerSingleton.getGame().start();
    }

}
```

However, this is where the error happens:

[image: The error]

What does this error mean and how can I prevent it? Also, are there any better approaches to implement this?

Note: I require access to the singleton instance from multiple classes, therefore I need this singleton class.

Comment: remove the `new` keyword

Comment: @skytreader That's an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `new` in that call:

```
new PlatformerSingleton.getGame().start();
```

Currently, it looks like you're trying to instantiate a class called `PlatformerSingleton.getGame` (a static nested class called `getGame` inside `PlatformerSingleton`).

You're looking for the static method inside `PlatformerSingleton`. Since it's *static*, you don't want to instantiate using `new` at all.

The compiler sees that the syntax is correct, but it doesn't find such class and thus throws an error. These kinds of errors are a bit tougher to correctly debug (as the actual error is *syntactical*), so you need to look a bit farther to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Don't add `new` in the line `new PlatformerSingleton.getGame().start();`

just change your line to:

```
PlatformerSingleton.getGame().start();
```

you are not creating `new` object here, you are just calling the `static` method of `PlatformerSingleton` class in which the object of the class is created using `Singleton Design Pattern`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `new`keyword (you don't need `new` because you're creating `PlatformerGame`instance inside of the `getGame` method):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     PlatformerSingleton.getGame().start();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `getGame()` is a `static` method, you do not need to use the `new` keyword to call the method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PlatformerSingleton.getGame().start(); // new keyword is not required
}
```

If `getGame()` was not `static`, only then it would have required an instance of `PlatformerSingleton` class for it to be called and that would have looked like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new PlatformerSingleton().getGame().start(); // if getGame() was a non-static method
}
```